# Azure Functions Application Insights Log Stream not showing log entries, but actual logs do show up in transaction search

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Test function on Linux consumption plan that just logs the HTTP request headers:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    log.LogInformation("Request headers:");
   
    foreach (var header in req.Headers)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"{header.Key} : {header.Value}");
    }

    ...
}
```

This is what the Application Insights log stream shows in real time:

```
2021-03-30T19:09:19Z   [Information]   C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2021-03-30T19:09:19Z   [Information]   Request headers:
```

As you can see, it showed the "Request headers:" entry, but the logged entries in the `foreach` loop do not show.

However, if I review the actual logs in application insights, they do contain the logged header entries.

But the point of the "log stream" is to show these things in near real time for convenient debugging. The actual transaction logs can lag by minutes.

Additionally, sometimes the logs do show up in the log stream (random), but oftentimes they don't. This function is not even in production so there is little to no traffic.

Is this just a performance limitation of the log stream? Is there a better way to go around this? I know I can debug functions locally, but the real requests have to hit the real function. Also since I prefer the Linux consumption plan, the "file system" log stream is not available.

Comment: If you are observing that the logs are missing in Application insight then please check you have enabled sampling or not : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling Also please check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#some-of-my-telemetry-is-missing

Comment: The logs themselves are not missing, as I can see them in log/transaction search. But lots of them do not show up in the "live" log stream for live debugging purpose.

Comment: @thankyoussd What do you mean with log/transaction search ? I also have the problem that my logs do not show up. In local debug mode they do though. I already checked all host.json settings. In Kudo I only see bash debug in `/home/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Function/my_function_trigger`

Comment: @DataBach I had pretty much given up on using the "Log Stream" feature. By "transaction search" I meant the Application Insight log transaction search.